# Горизонтальная прокрутка в iOS программировании(swift)

Tags: ios, swift, прокрутка

Как в Xcode лучшем образом реализовать горизонтальную прокрутку кнопок? Какие можете порекомендовать инструменты?(я только новичок)

Comment: Непонятно что вы имеете ввиду. Если прокрутка поверхности, на которой расположены кнопки - используйте UIScrollView

Comment: Если бы вы уточнили свой вопрос конкретным кейсом, было бы проще ответить на него качественно, ведь для горизонтальной прокрутки можно использовать как UIScrollView, так и UICollectionView все зависит от ситуации.